# Can't input text in textarea on selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I want to input text here (as attach img)

already tried to use, but doesn't work:

- sendkeys
  Got this err when use sendkeys >> `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable`
- arguments (JS)

The arguments are given below:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
WebElement el = getDriver().findElement(element);
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", el);
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].value='"+ word +"';", el);
```

element
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOa0F.png

HTML structure

```
<div class="col-sm-12 form-group"><div class="wrapper">note</div><textarea name="note" class="form-control" placeholder="Notes" data-testid="input-notes-on-create"></textarea></div>
```

Locator

```
By.cssSelector("div.col-md-7 form div.form-group:nth-child(3) > textarea.form-control");
```

or

```
By.xpath("//button[@data-testid='input-notes-on-create']");
```

Any idea why this happened? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you using executor instead of sendKeys ?

Comment: got this err when use sendkeys >> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

Comment: Please add the htm l

Comment: updated the desc

Comment: What is the locator used to find the elemnt >

Comment: By.cssSelector("div.col-md-7 form div.form-group:nth-child(3) > textarea.form-control");

Comment: the xpath adn css are for tow different elements ,

Comment: where you able to click with the css locator ?

Comment: The text area on the screen seems disabled. Are you even able to enter text manually?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> executor.executeScript("arguments[0].value='"+ word +"';", el);
> ```

You are setting up the attribute value but I am not exactly sure about this format so please try by adding `ExplicitWait` and below way of setting up attribute value.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement text = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[@data-testid='input-notes-on-create']")));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '" + word + "')", text);
```